# Bad Request: can't parse entities: Can't find end of the entity starting at byte offset 3589 ( in bot telegram api ) JavaScript

Tags: javascript, telegram-api

Hello and do not be tired.

My friends, I want to send a few messages in the telegram using a bot, but when I set parse_mode equal to Markdown, the first message is sent correctly, but for the second message, it gives a bad request.

I do not want to use HTML

The messages I send are written in such a code that it sends once every 50 characters, and if it reaches the end and it is less than 50, it should send as many as it could.

And I have 89 characters that can send 50 easily, but they can not send the next 39 and get objections

My code is in JavaScript

Thank you if you can help

(Meanwhile, these 89 characters do not differ from each other, they only interact in numerical value)

Thank you if you can help me

My code:

`

```
var len = 50;

if(key2 == "run? (I Money Bot)" || key2 == "time" || key2 == "run? (Title)"){
        } else {
          let getbody = sessionStorage.getItem("all");
          sessionStorage.setItem("all", getget + "#" + "["+key2+"] 
(https://t.me/joinchat/BZK0xRV8unyYfBmgQHnGUw) : " + Separate(" *"+value2+"* ") + " تومان") ; 
        if (i == sessionStorage.length-1){
            let body = sessionStorage.getItem("all").replace(/#/gi,"%0A%0A");
            console.log("all ==> "+sessionStorage.length);
            sessionStorage.removeItem("all");
            Bot(body + "%0A%0A╔══════════╗%0A @Puzzle_Bours_Gp](https://t.me/joinchat/BZK0xRV8unyYfBmgQHnGUw)%0A╚══════════╝%0A%0A" +
            "[Time : ](https://t.me/joinchat/BZK0xRV8unyYfBmgQHnGUw) : " + hou + ":" + min + ":" + sec);
            console.log("finish");
        }else if(i == len){
            let body = sessionStorage.getItem("all").replace(/#/gi,"%0A%0A");
            sessionStorage.removeItem("all");
            // console.log(sessionStorage.getItem("all").length);
            Bot(body + "%0A%0A╔══════════╗%0A [@Puzzle_Bours_Gp](https://t.me/joinchat/BZK0xRV8unyYfBmgQHnGUw)%0A╚══════════╝%0A%0A" +
            "[Time : ](https://t.me/joinchat/BZK0xRV8unyYfBmgQHnGUw) : " + hou + ":" + min + ":" + sec);
            len = len + 50;
            console.log("send characters");
        }
}
```

`

Bot() is the function for send text to bot in telegram.
I use %0A instead of \n because I set parse_mode to MarkDown.

Comment: _"My code is in JavaScript"_ - may you please share that code as a runnable [mcve]?

Comment: I put the code, but i can't share as a runnable because this code is for a special site

Comment: Special site or not, if we can’t run the code and reproduce it, it will be much harder to help

Comment: It is for a specific site. It is related to the Iran Stock Exchange site

Comment: I put this code in a loop that these conditions are met when len reaches that variable number i

Comment: See if your text is using any special character mentioned in Markdown like * or _. Because these characters are used for special purposes like bold and italic. And I guess \n is valid in MARKDOWN! Not sure though